# View deleted answers on your own questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-answers

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744725/can-i-use-deepzoomtools-dll-in-my-project-and-nuget-package?answertab=votes#tab-top) and I know that there is one more answer that has been deleted.

I know, if you have enough rep, you can see all deleted answers.

Would it be useful if the OP could see deleted answers, too?

Anyway, could someone help me to find the nick name of the user (maybe profile link) that posted and then, I guess, deleted another answer on my question?

Comment: Well, there's nothing much in this deleted answer which has been deleted by a moderator, on Meta votes show if we agree or not with your proposition, specially on feature-request posts.

Comment: @Tensibai thx, can you please give me profile link of this user? I want to contact him.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea, he was offering to make an internal follow up, that's likely to get only a partial feed back. If you wish to contact Microsoft about redistribution, there's a contact page on their site.

Comment: I want to view an answer that was deleted from my question, it was deleted IMO because it only showed code and no explanation, but I want the code even though I didn't vote for the answer.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers u can tell me, i’ll message it to you, where the question is?

Comment: @teovankot This one, --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306289/hard-coding-range-works-but-using-named-range-failes-excel-vba/55308145#55308145

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers https://github.com/zakharov-aa/REST-full-N-E-S-T-E-D/blob/master/soq

Comment: @teovankot Thanks, it was about as helpful as I remember, but I haven't looked at the code since Friday and wanted to check again. IMO I'd like this feature, but again, this is the first time I've ever wanted it in quite a few years of using SE Sites.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So it would be a terrible idea because:

1. There's multiples reasons an answer can be deleted (spam flag,
   moderator intervention, answer's author choice, 3 votes from >20k
   rep users)
2. There's a reason the answer has been deleted, either because is it incorrect or because it just blatantly spam

All in all, there's no reason to show to Question's author content that has been deleted, because it has been deleted for a reason.

Comment: What do you think about an option for at least showing the comments you wrote yourself? I took time researching for a comment, and now I can't recover it because somebody else decided to delete their answer.

Answer (score -10):

### Absolutely.

It would be useful for the OP to see a deleted answer provided that its deletion was not done by its author himself.

---

### Why not from the author?

It simply gives more security and privacy to that user, which takes precedence above all else.

- [ Sorted affairs can be handled by Moderation ]

---

### Why from moderation?

If Moderation has deleted an answer, it may be a form of moderation abuse, such as for reasons of censorship and the like, and should have more public visibility to help discourage or discover bad behaviour.

---

Edit:

My takeaway from discussing this in the comments:

1. This policy is more suitable for Stack Exchanges regarding business or the humanities.

   - [ It was written under the mistaken impression that this was the SE Meta. ]
2. This policy is not particularly useful for SO in particular, because there is little to no practical incentive for abuse.

Comment: The author of a post can take handle it themselves. If they think their post has been incorrectly deleted, then they can follow due process: [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/997587)

Comment: If we suspect every deletion of moderation abuse, why hide deleted answers at all then? Surely the question *asker* is just as qualified to assess deletion of an *answer* as everyone else who also isn't the answer author.

Comment: If an answer has been deleted, it been determined that, it serves absolutely nobody in the community. By allowing users with enough reputation moderator abuse cannot exist.

Comment: I mean... it's far more likely for author deletion to be abusive than moderation deletion. Moderation deletion is *far* more visible

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  Can you clarify what you mean by `If we suspect every deletion of moderation abuse,` << Not every deletion is done by a moderator, which was the distinction I made in my answer.

Comment: @SecurityHound Answers can be deleted for nefarious reasons, and sometimes the broader community is not a good metric to measure abuse if an SE has marginalized groups belonging to it.

Comment: @KevinB  `it's far more likely for author deletion to be abusive than moderation deletion.` Can you give an example? From my perspective, if I, an author, delete my own answer, its usually due to privacy concerns, and I am not sure how self deletion can be abusive to others? Thanks.

Comment: @Anon " Not every deletion is done by a moderator, which was the distinction I made in my answer." Most people conflate moderator and curators, so I assumed you didn't mean the interpretation in which *publicly elected and vetted* people were deemed *more suspicious* than random rep farmers. To be honest I am not sure what to say if you *only* distrust moderators – those seem to already be under *more* scrutiny, and by much more qualified people than askers (who are mostly the least familiar with SO and what's actual abuse against its rules).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  Thanks for clearing that up `those seem like to already be more under scrutiny,` That is true, and I have empathy, but I think it really depends on the subject matter. I think moderators of say the `politics stackexchange` should probably expect high pressure, criticism, and perpetual scrutiny as part of the job description, because that topic invites the most abuse. Not so much for `Electrical Engineering`, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Anon The overwhelming majority of post deletions are by either the author of the answer or the author of the question. Mods deleted 131k posts in 2022, vs 1.2mil by the community. Mods have nothing to gain, and a whole lot to lose, by maliciously deleting things. It's very public, in that anyone can go to meta and post a complaint and anyone with 10k rep and a link can see the content that was deleted. Users who are unaware of the safeguards and have less/nothing to lose are far more likely to be malicious.

Comment: There's also a massive numbers advantage, considering mods only deleted 131k posts in 2022, vs 1.2million by the community.

Comment: @KevinB `Mods have nothing to gain,` That heuristic only applies to a SE such as Stack Overflow. Anything touching business or the humanities will quickly introduce incentives for abuse.

Comment: I don't really care about the implications of this on smaller, irrelevant stacks.

Comment: @KevinB `smaller, irrelevant stacks` Catch 22: They are smaller and less relevant because the policy is inappropriate. Perhaps there should be a dual policy then.

Comment: @Anon I'd rather let the meta communities of the smaller sites discuss this themselves, where they are, rather than us decide for them how they'd prefer things be. We're on MSO at the moment, not MSE.

Comment: @Anon As a general comment: Can you please *quote* quotes, i.e. use " or ' or similar to mark them? `code formatting` is for, well, code.

Comment: @Anon Concerning your specific last points: If you are speaking in a broader context than just [so], I recommend to at least make this clear in the answer. Personally, I feel Meta-[SO] is simply the wrong place to make suggestions based purely on alleged abuse on *other* stacks.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi + KevinB Ah both of you are correct; Thanks for pointing that out. I didnt realize this was the SO meta. For whatever reason, I thought I was on the SE meta, so I maybe I will delete my answer in respect to that.

Comment: @Anon - Do you have specific examples of where both community users and community moderators failed to react to abuse like you describe?

Comment: @SecurityHound Not on this StackExchange, no.